# How to append a 2d array to 3d array?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a 3D nested list constructed like this:

```
[[[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[1,2]],[[-1,-1],[-2,-1],[-2,-2],[-1,-2]]]
```

and I want to concat to that `[[0,0]]` to get this result:

```
[[[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[1,2]],[[-1,-1],[-2,-1],[-2,-2],[-1,-2]],[[0,0]]]
```

I tried to use `numpy.append` and `column_stack` methods, but it complains about dimension mismatch. How to do that right?

Comment: Is this a `numpy.array` or a built-in `list`?

Comment: if it's a list then `a.append([[0,0]])` should work.

Comment: you can't do this in `numpy` but possible in `list` with `append` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that once you have a `numpy` array with shape `(2, 4, 2)`, you cannot really append another array with shape `(1, 1, 2)` unless you treat lists as objects (i.e. you are appending an element to an array of size `2` so that in the end you have an array of size `3`).

If you have a `numpy` array of `list` objects you won't be able to benefit from most of the functionality provided by `numpy` so perhaps explain in a bit more detail what exactly you are trying to achieve here.

```py
>>> a = np.array([[[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[1,2]],[[-1,-1],[-2,-1],[-2,-2],[-1,-2]]])
>>> b = np.array([[[0, 0]]])
>>> a.shape, b.shape
((2, 4, 2), (1, 1, 2))
>>> c = np.array(a.tolist() + b.tolist())
>>> c
array([list([[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]]),
       list([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-2, -2], [-1, -2]]), list([[0, 0]])],
      dtype=object)
>>> c.shape
(3,)
>>> c.tolist()
[[[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]],
 [[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-2, -2], [-1, -2]],
 [[0, 0]]]
```

The last value is the list you seem to be looking for. You don't have to go through this process with `numpy` to get it and can simply `append` as others have suggested.

Comment: ```[[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[1,2]]``` and ```[[-1,-1],[-2,-1],[-2,-2],[-1,-2]]``` are coordinates of rectangles vertices and ```[[0,0]]``` is a point's coordinates, which I want to add to array which has rectangles (for later processing)

Comment: numpy is designed to help you work with vectors, matrices, tensors etc. it allows you to perform all kinds of manipulations, however, you cannot have "rows" that are incomplete so you probably want to work with pure lists, and simply append your point to the list of previous "shapes"

Answer (score 0):

guess what, I can just use default `append` function; I didn't know that function is not returning the new array

Comment: Yes, be careful about using `numpy` functions.  If you start with a list, and want a list result, using `numpy` is often slower, and possibly wrong.